# limiting version attributes in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, version, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid::Versioning which works great except that I would like to prevent several fields from being versioned.

There's not a lot of info written about it in the docs so I'm not sure how to do this.

http://mongoid.org/docs/extras.html

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Versioning

  # keep at most 5 versions of a record
  max_versions 5
end
```

They show how to skip a version altogether but not how to restrict certain fields from being versioned.

Any ideas?

UPDATE

I found something like this digging through the code, but I'm not sure how to use it.

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/versioning.rb#L90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably find a way to do this, but I would suggest checking out this gem instead.

https://github.com/aq1018/mongoid-history

```
track_history   :on => [:title, :body],       # I want to track title and body fields only. Default is :all
                  :modifier_field => :modifier, # Adds "referened_in :modifier" to track who made the change. Default is :modifier
                  :version_field => :version,   # Adds "field :version, :type => Integer" to track current version. Default is :version
                  :track_create   =>  false,    # Do you want to track document creation? Default is false
                  :track_update   =>  true,     # Do you want to track document updates? Default is true
                  :track_destroy  =>  false,    # Do you want to track document destruction? Default is false
```

Comment: I like it, but I'd like to see if there's another possibility which doesn't use another gem?

Answer (score 4):

All Field has option `:versioned` true by default If you don't want this versionned you can pass false. By exemple I want name versioned but no login

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Versioning

  field :name, :type => String
  field :login, :type => String, :versioned => false
end
```

You can pass the `:versioned` option in embed association too.

You can override this option by iterating over the `.fields` on your Document.

So in your code you can add avoid versionned on some field by creating a little methode :

```
class User

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Versioning
  include Mongoid::Voteable

  field :name, :type => String
  field :login, :type => String

  def self.avoid_versioned(*unversioned_fields)
    unversioned_fields.each do |f|

      fe = self.fields[f.to_s]
      fe.options[:versioned] = false if fe

      re = self.relations[f.to_s]
      re[:versioned] = false if re

    end
  end
  avoid_versioned( :login, :votes )
end
```

Comment: i'm trying to use it in combination with mongoid_voteable, so there's no way for me to pass the ':versioned => false' to it.  Is there no other way to explicitly tell it to leave a certain embedded object alone? or do it opt in instead of opt out?

Comment: I write a method to do the job if all of your fields are already define. I add you mongoid_voteable exemple.

Comment: unless i'm missing something in the implementation, it doesn't seem to work. I get 'undefined method `foreign_key_suffix' for Mongoid::Relations::Embedded::Many:Class' It's still trying to version the :votes association ;-(

Comment: in mongoid_voteable, votes it's not an embed Are you sure using it ? https://github.com/jcoene/mongoid_voteable/blob/master/lib/mongoid_voteable.rb#L9

Comment: sorry i used the wrong name, it's voteable_mongo... https://github.com/angelim/voteable_mongo  it saves something like 'votes: {"up"=>[], "down"=>[], "faceless_up_count"=>0, "faceless_down_count"=>0, "up_count"=>0, "down_count"=>0, "total_up_count"=>0, "total_down_count"=>0, "count"=>0, "point"=>0, "ratio"=>0, "ip"=>[]}'

Comment: I improve my `avoid_versioned` to stop versioned in relation too. You need call this avoid_versioned method only after all of your `voteable` call.

Comment: I still get the same error about foreign keys and it all works great as soon as I comment out the Mongoid::Versioning ;-(

Comment: If it's it's an Referenced association, you need pass the foreign_key in `avoid_versioned` method. We need more concret code to fix it.

Comment: I found this bit mentioning a foreign key: https://github.com/angelim/voteable_mongo/blob/9625aa6f7e14e293415d6098d4a5350489badf8d/lib/voteable_mongo/integrations/mongoid.rb

Comment: setting `:versioned => false` worked for me. No idea why something like this isn't in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You may skip versioning at any point in time by wrapping the persistence call in a versionless block.

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Versioning
end

person.versionless do |doc|
  doc.update_attributes(name: "Theodore")
end
```

Comment: I saw that in the docs, but I don't need to do it on a per record basis.  I need it on a particular field permanently.